# How to import css javascript & HTML into block?

Tags: javascript, theming

Is there anyway to import my css and javascript external files into HTML block?
I really try to make css and js inline with HTML but Drupal stripe the tags, thus i try [syntax highlighter](https://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter) and [cpn](https://drupal.org/project/cpn) but nothing changed.

Comment: Is this a custom block, or did you make you block from the admin/structure/block/add link on the block admin page?

Comment: yes i make new block